# Неправильный результат при использовании регулярного выражения, созданного с помощью new RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Написал регулярное выражение:

```
var v0 = '0as',
    v1 = '2as',
    obj = '0as 1as 2as 3as 4as';

re0 = new RegExp(v0 +'(.*)'+ v1, 'g');

// первый пример, выводится неправильно:
// вывод: ["0as 1as 2", " 1as ", index: 0, input: "0as 1as 2as 3as 4as"]
console.log(re0.exec(obj));

// второй пример, выводится правильно:
// вывод: ["0as 1as 2as", " 1as ", index: 0, input: "0as 1as 2as 3as 4as"]
console.log(/0as(.*)2as/.exec(obj));
```

То есть нужно сделать так, чтобы в случае использования `RegExp` вывод был таким же, как и во втором примере (`"0as 1as 2as"`, а не `"0as 1as 2"`).

В чем ошибка?

Comment: В [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e961mq64/) в обоих случаях я вижу `"0as 1as 2as"` (Opera 43.0.2442.806). Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего что-то связаное с приведением типов при конкатенации, когда 2ас приводится к числу 2.

Comment: @ReinRaus, какое ещё приведение типов? И с какой бы это стати оно так приводилось?

Comment: @Qwertiy хз что там происходит, но очень на это похоже. Регулярные выражения настолько просты, что в них нет ошибки. Принимаем за истину, что автор нигде не ошибся и пишет то, что видит. Тогда в регулярное выражение вместо 2ас попало просто 2, что очень похоже на приведение типов. Я просто предположил, не утвердил.

Comment: @ReinRaus 1. приведение типов к числу не происходит для `+`. 2. `2as` приводится к число `NaN`, а не `2`. 3. Написанное в вопросе не воспроизводится. 4. Проблема, скорее всего, в exec, флаге g и многократном переиспользовании регулярки.

Comment: Я лишь предположил, что автор пишет то, что видит. Если он видит что-то другое- такое предположение уже сделали чуть ниже :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял должны без пробелов быть. Если да то вот короткий пример:

```
'0as 1as 2as 3as 4as'.match(/(\d\w*)/g)
```

Если только цифры то:

```
'0as 1as 2as 3as 4as'.match(/(\d)/g)
```